# Angular - how to show dropdown selected value in textbox

Tags: angular

I am trying do following:
1. Select option from drop-down box
2. Fetch value from DB according to that
3. Display it in textbox

I did with first 2-steps but not getting how to bind returned value from function to that specific textbox.

For Ex. There is select box with Distributor names and on select of distributor name I want to display related product rate from another table in text box.
Distributor is one table and Rates in another table

Comment: cant you assign the value from function to the ngModule variable of textbox ?

Comment: Right. Want to assign value to textbox  which will be return value of function which I am calling onChange of select drop down box.

Comment: Add some sample in your question data for give some example for you filter condition.

Comment: For Ex. There is select box with Distributor names and on select of distributor name I want to display related product rate from another table in text box.

Comment: Please see i am update filter concept for using sample data and printing console.You can change your data and print your convenient.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me

Comment: Glad to help you.Did you got what you expected?.Please feel free to upvote also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example,Iam created this using sample data you can replace actual value.

Html File,

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectionModel" (change)="onChange()">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Choose Name</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngValue]="item"> {{item.name}} </option>  
</select>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

Typescript File,

```
    public showRate;
    public selectionModel;
    public data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Muthu",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Jeeva",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Gokul",
        }
      ];

  public rateData:any[]=[
        {
          rate: 10,
          name: "Muthu",
        },
        {
          rate: 20,
          name: "Jeeva",
        },
        {
          rate: 30,
          name: "Gokul",
        }
  ]
      onChange() {    
        this.name = this.selectionModel.name;

       //For one Result use find method
        this.showRate=this.rateData.find((o)=>o.name == this.selectionModel.name));

       //For more Result use filter method
        this.showRate=this.rateData.filter((o)=>o.name == this.selectionModel.name));

     console.log("Your Filtered Data Here",this.showRate);
      }
```

Output Screenshot,

[image]
[image]

Comment: On select name, I want to call a function to fetch the related value from a database and display that value in textbox.

Comment: use filter for get related data.

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty easy, use [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel):

**for Angular 2+**:

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox" [(ngModel)]="textbox" name="textbox" />
```

and then in typescript:

```
export class SimpleNgModelComp {
  textbox: string = '';

  setValue() { this.textbox= 'somevalue'; }
}
```

**For angular js**:

```
 <input type="text" id="txtBox" ng-model="textbox" name="textbox" />
```

and then in controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textbox = "somevalue";
});
```

ng-model is a [Two-Way-Binding](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) directive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to bind textbox with the return value of function which I want to call onChange() of select drop down box.

Comment: it will be the same practice.